# recognize kanji

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image]

completely stuck on this kanji. recognized lower part, but not the top.
よろしくお願いします！

Comment: It looks like an elephant, and funnily enough, it is the character for elephant.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like 印象 to me.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: [印象]{いんしょう}を　ひっくり返すと　[象印(ぞうじるし)](http://www.zojirushi-world.com/)

Comment: @Choko それ川柳？ギャグ？どうやってオトすんだろ・・

Comment: @非回答者　オチは特にないです･･･　体重をひっくり返すと重体になる、みたいな、漢字の言葉遊び。　[象印好印象]{ぞうじるしこういんしょう}、逆さにしても象印好印象。